# fundamental solution of heat alike IBVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

What is the best quickest way to find fundamental solution $K(t,x,y)$ of the following initial boundary-value problem
\begin{align}
z_t&=z_{xx}-\beta z\qquad (0\le x\le l,t>0)\\
z_x(0,t)&=z_x(l,t)=0\quad (t>0),\\
z(x,0)&=z_0(x)\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\qquad (0\le x\le l)
\end{align}

Fourier transform? Or what else?